# Integrate [new-twitter] into [twitter]

Tags: discussion, tags

For [new-twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-twitter) we have **2** (two) questions (all asked back in 2010), **1** (one) follower to it and... we have "new" Twitter working like a charm for past three years.

Shouldn't we integrate these two questions into [twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) and remove [new-twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-twitter)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case just retag the questions. The [new-twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-twitter) tag will then just disappear from the system.

If there were 10's or even 100's of questions with the tag I'd create a synonym, but for such a low number it's not worth it. Even as a low rep user you can suggest the edits and when they get accepted you'll get some more reputation.

Comment: Thanks! Done. Cheers! :]